# Understanding the meaning of Computational Order of Convergence

Tags: iterative-method, convergence

I am a postgraduate student with interest in numerical methods for solving nonlinear systems of equations. I have read some papers that discussed about 'computational order of convergence' for some iterative methods for example [Increasing the order of convergence of iterative schemes for solving nonlinear systems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712005249), but still I can't explain it or implement it practically using MATLAB.

Please, can somebody help me with a good reference to understand how to compute the computational order of convergence for my proposed iterative method?

Comment: Are you asking how the "order of convergence" is defined? Or how to find out about the order of convergence of a method you have implemented?

Comment: I am not asking about how the order of convergence is defined, rather I will like to became rich in the "computational order of convergence" literature.

Comment: Every book about numerical methods has a section on determining the order of convergence experimentally.